# How to use automapper from string to List of Strings

Tags: c#, automapper

Using automapper how do we convert a string separated with spaces to a List  ?

Data:

```
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4
```

Class:

```
public class myFooList
{
   public int myId;
   public List<string> myListOfStrings;
}
```

Using automapper defaults.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<data,myFooList>()        
    .ForMember(d=>d.mListOfStrings, s=>s.MapFrom(s=>s.Data));
```

I get data in the form of one line per character.

Ex:

```
f
o
o
1

f
o
o
2
```

etc..etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mapper.CreateMap<data,myFooList>()

    .ForMember(d=>d.mListOfStrings, s=>s.MapFrom(s=>s.Data.Split()));`

Looks like automapper makes a reasonable assumption and enumerates the string character by character. 
Just be explicit about the Split.

nvoigt's suggestion is also correct - are you sure you want to use automapper?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to split a string and create a list from it:

```
var text = "foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4";
var delimiters = new char [] {' '};

var myListOfStrings = text.Split(delimiters).ToList();
```

I've never needed AutoMapper, so you may want to work from here...